# Invalid token ')' and '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#

The error occurs on all occurrences of '{' and ')'
I don't see anything wrong?

```
// Kills the game object
Destroy{}(gameObject);

// Removes this script instance from the game object
//Destroy(this);

// Removes the rigidbody from the game object
Destroy{}(rigidbody);

// Kills the game object in 5 seconds after loading the object
Destroy{}(5, gameObject);

// When the user presses Ctrl, it will remove the script 
// named FooScript from the game object
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1")) 
        GetComponent<FooScript>();
    {
        Destroy(GetComponent<MonoScript>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need `{}`? Simply remove the `{}` in all cases, and it will work. `Destroy{}(gameObject);` should be `Destroy(gameObject);`

Comment: ...except in the `void Update()`.  :-)

Comment: @LarsTech Yes, I guess I wasn't clear - I meant all cases of specifically `{}`, not curly brackets in general :)

Comment: If I remove them I get an error on Destroy stating "'Destroy.Destroy(gameObject)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial"

Comment: In case you aren't aware it, but `Destroy(GetComponent<MonoScript>());` is not a part of that "if" clause.  Your brackets have made that look potentially confusing.

Comment: Is this your entire program?  Or is this part of a class?

Comment: It is just part of a class

Answer (score 0):

All those `Destroy` methods should be part of some method.
They cannot be dangling in a class like that.
In addition, `{}` are used when opening a new scope, not when calling a method. The code should potentially look like:

```
// What are these? They should be in some method
void DestroyAll()
{
    // Kills the game object
    Destroy(gameObject);

    // Removes this script instance from the game object
    //Destroy(this);

    // Removes the rigidbody from the game object
    Destroy(rigidbody);

    // Kills the game object in 5 seconds after loading the object
    Destroy(5, gameObject);
}

// When the user presses Ctrl, it will remove the script 
// named FooScript from the game object
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
    {
        Destroy(GetComponent<FooScript>());
    }
}
```